# How can I control what parts of the image should show when I minimize the window?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image on my page and it's created using photoshop. The image has text in the middle. When I minimize the window the image shrinks and the text becomes smaller instead of scaled.

I tried:

```
.img{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

How can I make it when I minimize the window the text will stay the same and the image will be cut from the sides?

Thank you

Comment: Not really finding your question clear. Would it be bossible for you to create a working snippet of your problem or a [**JsFiddle Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/) please, thank you.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/scaled-proportional-blocks-with-css-and-javascript/

Comment: media queries and background image

Answer (score 1):

img element is meant to show a whole image. To display only a part of image, you'd better use a block element with background specified in css. This allows you to specify the size of viewport and position of the image separately.

For example, in html,

```
<div class='my-image'></div>
```

in css,

```
.my-image {
   background-image: url(path-to-image.jpg);
   background-position: center center;
   background-size: auto auto; // This is the default
}
```

This allows you to position the image centered in the div. No matter how big the div it is, the image size will stay the same(thus only the center part is visible because of the clipping).

For more details about background in css, please read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background